Solving $x^2+2mx+3m-2$, where $m \in \mathbb R$ is a parameter.
The Problem:
Let the equation be $x^2+2mx+3m-2$, where $m \in\mathbb R$ is a parameter.
a) find $m \in\mathbb R$ so that the equation has real solutions
b) find $m \in\mathbb R$ so that the equation has two real solutions $x_1, x_2$ that verify the equality: $$\frac{1}{x_1}+ \frac{1}{x_2}= \frac{3} {4}$$
The Idea:
a) we know that a quadratic equation has real solutions if: $$ \delta =4m^2-4(3m-2)=4(m-1)(m-2) \geq 0 \implies (m-1)(m- 2) \geq 0$$ and from here we have 2 cases:

$m-1\geq 0, m-2\geq 0 \implies m \geq 2$

$m-1 \leq 0, m-2 \leq 0 \implies m\leq 1$


$\implies m\in R- (1,2)$
b) For point be I wrote that $\frac{1}{x_1}+ \frac{1}{x_2}= \frac{3} {4}= \frac{x_1+ x_2}{x_1 * x_2}$
I then thought of using the formula of Vitae and calculated $x_1 * x_2= 3m-2, x_1+ x_2=-2m$ and substituted them in the initial equation:
$$\frac{-2m}{3m-2}=\frac{3}{4} \implies -8m=9m-6=> m=\frac{6}{17}$$
I put this with the tag solution verification because when I try to check my solution for point b0 I don't get to the wanted solution...also I'm not sure is my rationament for both points is ok.

For b, what was "the wanted solution"?

The $x_{1,2}$ I get by plugging in your $m$ into the original equation verify the equality in part b.

@CalvinLin Sorry, the way i said that isn't corect. I mean that the given condition $\frac{1}{x_1}+ \frac{1}{x_2}= \frac{3}{4}$ isn't happening when I have $m= \frac{6}{17}$

@Andrei Oooo...so my solution is right?

I agree with Andrei that $m = 6/17$ is correct. So can you elaborate on how the given condition isn't happening?

With your solution, $m=6/17$, the equation becomes
$$x^2+\frac{12}{17}x-\frac{16}{17}=0$$
The solutions are
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac 6{17}\pm\sqrt{\frac{36}{17^2}+\frac{16}{17}}=\frac{-6\pm\sqrt{308}}{17}$$
Then $$\frac1{x_1}+\frac1{x_2}=\frac{17}{-6+\sqrt{308}}+\frac{17}{-6-\sqrt{308}}\\=17\frac{-6-\sqrt{308}-6+\sqrt{308}}{36-308}\\=\frac{17\cdot 12}{17\cdot 16}=\frac34$$

Suggestion: $\frac1{x_1}+\frac1{x_2}$ =\frac((x_2) + (x_1)}{(x_2) (x_1)} = \frac (sum o f roots}{product of roots} = ...$

@Mick The original poster started the same way, but it seems like he/she had issues with verifying that this approach is correct

No problem. jJut a suggestion.
